# Connect to SQL using localhost\SQLEXPRESS works but not local_ip\SQLEXPRESS

Tags: sql-server, localhost

I am trying to connect using SSMS to a local SQL Server Express install.

In SSMS when I use `localhost\SQLEXPRESS` it connects but using local IP of `192.168.0.6\SQLEXPRESS` it is not working.

Other computers on the network can connect to the `192.168.0.6\SQLEXPRESS` just fine.
Its like the lookback for the IP isn't working correctly. The server is a Virtual Machine running server 2019 on a host running server 2019 also.

Is this a limitation of SQL Server Express? or some config issue with SQL or windows? Any help would be great.

Comment: This is likely nothing to do what th SQL Server and more network. Seems that, for whatever reason, when you use your network IP on the host your device isn't picking up the DNS record and so looping back. I suspect if you were to try to connect to any services running on your PC with the network IP, they would all fail to connect.

Comment: Probably you haven't enabled IP for the instance, and are using Shared Memory.  It's disabled by default for Express Edition, and you need to enable it in the SQL Server configuration manager.